# Auto-margin container with image :before and :after as container left/right border?

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to wrap a Youtube video in a container with auto margins, then apply 2 images as a kinda border to the immediate left and right with :before and :after. The result should be that the browser windows centres on the video, but when the browser window is expanded then the images to the left and right are revealed.

Pretty sure I'm going wrong on the positioning. I'm not even sure if :before and :after is the best way to achieve this. All suggestions to get the desired outcome are welcome.

*EDIT: The left image's right edge should always line up with the left edge of the video, and vica versa for the right side image (left edge lines up with right edge of video), so they sort of act like inline-block elements. Could this be achieved with a background image behind the entire video maybe?*

Here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
   <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="960" height="540"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/orosuMZsn7I?autoplay=0&origin=http://example.com"
    frameborder="0"/>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
<style>
.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 540px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.container:before {
    content: url(img/surround_02.jpg);
    height: 540px;
    width:211px;
    position:absolute;
}
.container:after {
    content: url(img/surround_03.jpg);
    height: 540px;
    width:218px;
    position:absolute;
}
.container iframe {
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You can use images with borders, which might be a better approach. You could nest the rules in a media query to reveal only after a min-width. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since the question was edited so that my previous answer didn't fit anymore, I came up with a new solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/fusuhga6/3/

Again, pretty straightforward:
Everything is in the DIV that holds the Youtube-video, which has

```
`position:relative` 
`margin: 0 auto`
```

in order to center it horizontally.

The two images are background-images in two absolute-positioned DIVs that are *in* the #youtube DIV, but positioned like this:

```
#leftPic, #rightPic {  
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 200px;
  }
 #leftPic {
   left: -90px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/90x200) no-repeat top right;
 }
  #rightPic {
    right: -90px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/90x200) no-repeat top left;
 }
```

So their left/right offsets correspond to their (fixed) width. Since they are attached to the #youtube DIV, that whole group will be centered.

Now, when the window becomes narrower than those three blocks together, the #youtube DIV remains centered, and the other two remain aligned to it as before, with their _outer_parts being cut off.

That should fulfill your criteria...

Comment: Fantastic, that's the one Johannes! Chosen as the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting situation, so I played around a bit and came up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/fusuhga6/2/

Rather simple HTML structure and CSS:

`#Container` has a percentage width (100%), plus a max-width in px that equals the overall sum of the youTube iFrame's width plus the width of the two images. It's `margin: 0 auto` make it center horizontally inide the browser window or surrounding container. The two images are included as two background-images of that container, one aligned left, the other aligned right (top). All elements have the same height.

The size of the Youtube-DIV is fixed (250px x 200px in the fiddle example). It also has `margin: 0 auto` to center it horizontally within the #Container.

The nice thing about this method: In larger windows the whole thing is centered in its full width (Youtube + 2 images). When the window becomes narrower, first the empty space left and right shrinks. Once the #Container spans the full width of the window and becomes narrower with the window, the YouTube frame stays centered, and the images become narrower and narrower.

Hmmmm.

Comment: Nicely done, good use of background images, no need for the pseudo-elements!

Comment: Excellent work, this was a really nice solution, however I had omitted a vital piece of information! The left image's right edge should always line up with the left edge of the video, and vica versa for the right side image (left edge lines up with right edge of video), so they sort of act like inline-block elements. I shall edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: @TFOH as you say in your edit, you could use my structure and instead of 2 background images use just one that you center in the surrounding #Container. For that background image you'd have to create a new img that contains the two original images with exactly the empty space in the middle that the youtube frame takes up.

Answer (score 1):

Having a hard time imagining the final goal, but here's a couple things that could hopefully help.

First, to really make use of absolute positioning with CSS, a containing element should be position: relative;  This is a little confusing, but your absolute positioning is relative to the nearest parent element.  [This article by Chris Coyier on CSS positioning is very helpful](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).  The default position of an element is "static" so unless you're declaring another element as relative, the absolute positioning may not be responding how you want. In this case, you could safely make .container position:relative.

Second, just some cleanup in your markup and CSS, you're using a self-closing `<iframe>` tag when you first declare your iframe.  You should remove that erroneous /> and just use a >, and then you can use your `</iframe>`. Currently, you're closing the iframe with /> and then also closing it again. I think that'll just result in a syntax error, but still... Doesn't hurt to clean it up.

```
<div class="container">
   <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="960" height="540"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/orosuMZsn7I?autoplay=0&origin=http://example.com"
    frameborder="0">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

(removed the slash from just after *frameborder="0" />*)

The last bit of cleanup is that you can re-write your margin declaration to be margin: 0 auto; (or if you want some top margin, add that in place of the 0).  If you think of CSS declarations like margin and padding like a clock, then:

```
margin: 10px 30px 5px 25px;
```

means

```
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 25px;
```

If you don't fill any values in after the first declaration, then they all inherit that declaration.  So:

```
margin: 5px;
```

Ends up rendering as:

```
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
```

If you declare the first two:

```
margin: 5px auto;
```

Then it will render as:

```
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
```

Anyway these don't really answer your question, but if you can give a link or mock specifically to what you're trying to do, it might help figure it out.