# static background image in responsive website - not resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I made small reposnsive website. Everything looks good but not a background. Problem is that this background is an image and shows 2 womans on sides (left and right). Part of them bodies must be always visible on sides. But when I change resolutions Background is resizing to:/ How to made a background static?
background-attachment:fixes; not helps me

here is my code:

```
body{ 
    background:url(/images/bg.jpg) top; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    width:100%; 
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Add your code, because we can't help you without it. Otherwise this will be closed as offtopic.

Comment: here u have it my friend: http://travi-design.pl/s.html

Comment: This is not code , this is html page..send us the code snippet which has issue..

Comment: yes but there u can see all page and find the solution. The problem is only background, I need to have it not resizing. Here u have body CSS code body{
 background:url(/images/bg.jpg) top;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

Comment: If you need to display something always at the left and right sides than it would be better if you put the "two woman" into two separated divs and position them absolute.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your CSS:

- You're not specifying how big the background should be
- You're not specifying how the background should display
- You're not specifying how the background should be positioned;
- You're incorrectly specifying the background.

Here's what you should be using:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://travi-design.pl/klienci/rea_strefamarek/szablon/images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd split that image in two seperate images and use them as I described once in an earlier post for a similar situation (that time with a video in the middle): https://stackoverflow.com/a/34192574/5641669 and Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/fusuhga6/2/

The `#Container` element has a percentage width (100%), plus a `max-width` in px that equals the overall sum of the center element's width plus the width of the two images. It's `margin: 0 auto` make it center horizontally inside the browser window or surrounding container. The two images are included as two background-images of that container, one aligned left, the other aligned right (top). All elements have the same height. 
The size of the video element is fixed (250px x 200px in the fiddle example). It also has `margin: 0 auto` to center it horizontally within `#Container`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*, html{ margin: 0;
  padding: 0;}
body{
  background: #c4c4c4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content{
  position: relative;
}

.backgroundBox{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  
}

.leftSide{
  background: #a9a9a9;
  left: 0px;
}

.rightSide{
  background: #bbbbbb;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftSide backgroundBox"></div>
<div class="rightSide backgroundBox"></div>

<div class="content">
<h1>Page Content</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </p>
</div>
```